# How to create a link without creating directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

Have you seen some websites which have some links and webpages but no directiry exists!

For example domain.com/projects/exampleproject

Here **project** directory does not exist on web server and .php extention have been removed!!!

Is it possible?

Comment: You've seen it, so it's possible ;) It's url rewriting, btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called url rewritting as stated in alot of comments. A tutorial on this would be here: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ and domain.com/projects/exampleproject can also be achieved by having a directory called exampleproject and having index.php or index.html inside of it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You need to use url rewriting. Read the content of this link and you will be able to do it yourself.
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/